# Detection of 3 phase system

Tags: voltage, power, current, ac, three-phase

I need some help with the below circuit.

Circuit:

3-phase AC circuit (3 phases and neutral). 120deg phase shift between the 3.

I need to provide a signal to the Microcontroller.

If one of the phases is missing, or most importantly, if phase difference is greater than 120deg between any of the two phases, then I need to convey this information to the MCU.

Initially, I thought of using an OR gate IC and giving the output of the gate to the MCU. But using the OR gate, it is not possible to convey the phase difference information to the MCU.

Comment: Basicly you need three zero-crossing or polarity detectors then coney that information to the microcontroller and have the microcontroller compare the timing to get phase angle

Comment: This is the real world. Phase angle is never exactly 120.000 degrees, one of them will be over,  perhaps pick a different threshold.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні, sure. Could you give an idea on how to identify the phase difference between the any two phases if the thresholds are different?

Comment: use timers in the microcontroller to measure the time difference,

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні, I have only one MCU pin.

Comment: connect it to another mcu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One single two-state signal to detect phase problems of a three-phase system:

Use one comparator each to compare each phase to zero and generate the *exclusive or* of the comparator output signals.
Each comparator output changes state whenever the potential difference at its inputs changes sign, one input being tied to the reference potential ("ground"), whenever the input signal "crosses zero".
An ExOr's output (equivalently, an ExNOr's output) changes state whenever an odd number of inputs changes state; in particular, when *one* input changes state.
An MCU can monitor the time between state changes, there should be six for every mains period.
Evenly spaced when the phase difference is 120° or 2π/3.

Here's a [sketch at falstad.com](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMkAcAWA7ATjigbGHojFinHkiAnBHAKYC0iiAUAEpIYVYXMBMIHuEo0QAZj55IFCH2hY0YnMT5KxiHGKhx2nXlgH8kB4YioQJUmcLCQdHRFxB8UKJIgEu3EM6MvThBjkwBSU4FTUNOC1bHTQwMz549wExMDQUyhQAHQBnRDg8pkL82Fg8sAroMXxXPDQUF0Q0GjExPOIy8Dy+StKygaQKlnjE5N63NIyJrI6S4o6BvuXISQ9VNAM0InqMNDRFrr7ew6WYIdywEYTnZKnxdIeMsxz8+YLT8sui2z4sf48zTAezSWAwJU6sG6uRO-TOPmGACc9IIKEkIEIfEsWMj0ajbj4XKZYCwAOYEpBEvHNDIQK7kvF8JIUvF0skUiSyO5iaxXZGOfSeZIaARYgY4ikilnMsV8lmuDm9YkwCUC5wKxkK2UkgoZHluGb7A1gbziKhUFgAdyezhN4jwxu8VptRn1xlFzvuXodzhlLAAsiAjba3Js0XbZHZdDVnh4gxJMnSg7QbNoJfdXehE0gScj7jMY9nIenHl6s0ZZSwAPbGJDWeKkc22Mw+FhAA) - try changing one of the phase angles.

Electrical safety may mandate to isolate signal processing from "the three phases".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain a bit more or an image of the circuit will help me understand better?

Comment: Thank you for the simulation. Could you please write a couple of lines to understand the working of the circuit, please?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really appreciate the explanation. I have 2 last questions. 1. When one of the 3- phase input is left floating, i.e, the inverting terminal is unconnected to the 3-phase input. In that case, the output will still be the same as when all 3-phases are working fine. In this case, what can be done? 2. Could you please tell me how to do the isolation? Some suggestion on this, please?

Comment: In this [improved falstad setup](https://tinyurl.com/27ulxkaz) (*finally* got it to show 3 phases so one can see "zero crossing"), move one of the sources to the left to disconnect it. To transfer something electrical to an [isolated level](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation), convert it to a different form of energy. In power distribution, magnetic fields are used in isolating transformers. For signalling, [optocouplers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) are more common; transferring comparator outputs offers more flexibility than just parity (ExOr output).

Comment: Thank you. So, the non-inverting terminal's resistor has to connected to neutral of the 3-phase & the output of the comparator or more so the output of the OR gate should be referenced to the PCB digital/MCU ground, am I correct?

Comment: I wish the question title was more specific: reading *most importantly, [is the] phase difference greater than 120deg between any [two of three phases]* + *I have only one MCU pin*, I spell out one way to provide a 1-bit signal allowing a typical MCU to detect deviations from "symmetrical zero crossings" (and mentioned security). There are other problems with phase voltage in a 3-phase system: noise, voltage (`one of the phases is missing` as an extreme case), harmonics, frequency, offset… I think these as well as *How to do a mains zero crossing detector* require separate/rephrased questions.

Answer (score 3):

If the voltages on each phase are equal, this will give zero volts output if the phases are 0, 120, and 240 degrees.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjitZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Balanced voltages and phase angles:
[image: balanced voltages and phase angles]

Voltages with unbalanced phase p1=0, p2=120, p3=250
[image: p1=0, p2=120, p3=250]

Voltages with unbalanced amplitude p1=0, p2=120, p3=240, V(p3)=160
[image: p1=0, p2=120, p3=240, V(p3)=160]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What happens if the voltage varies by some amount say +/-10V? 2. Also, Is the ground of the signals, neutral AC? Or a digital ground of the MCU?

Comment: Sorry - captions added.